# Ruby inheritance, modules or subclasses

Tags: ruby, inheritance, module

I'm working with the Tumblr API right now and they have various types of posts (text, photo, video, quote, link, etc.). I'd like to make one parent class TumblrPost and then a bunch of sub-classes such as TumblrTextPost. If I do this, would there be a way to access each post via TumblrPost (ie. TumblrPost.all.each) regardless of sub-class? (NOTE: I'm using MongoDB and Mongoid)

Or should I maybe make each sub-class a module and then just do class TumblrPost include TumblrTextPost, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you're talking about accessing each TumblrPost instance or each TumblrPost subclass.

If you want to access each instance, you can set up a class instance variable in TumblrPost and update with every new instance in the constructor:

```
class TumblrPost
  @all_instances = []

  class << self
    attr_accessor :all_instances
  end

  def initialize
    TumblrPost.all_instances << self
  end
end

TumblrTextPost = Class.new(TumblrPost)

t1 = TumblrPost.new
t2 = TumblrTextPost.new

puts TumblrPost.all_instances
```

If, on the other hand, you want to be able to iterate over each of the subclasses of TumblrPost, you can use the inherited hook to keep track of them.

```
class TumblrPost
  @all_subclasses = []

  class << self
    attr_accessor :all_subclasses
  end

  def self.inherited(subclass)
    @all_subclasses << subclass
  end
end

TumblrTextPost = Class.new(TumblrPost)
puts TumblrPost.all_subclasses
```

---

Source: Russ Olsen's [Eloquent Ruby](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321584104)